# Architectural pattern / style for downtime

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, architecture, amazon-cloudfront

Is there a recommended architectural pattern for handling maintenance downtime in a system say on AWS? One approach suggested to me was to have a backup JSON file on an s3 bucket and fallback to that where the main API is down. Then have a /healthcheck end-point on the main API that the client could first check. The problem I have with this is that it requires the client to make several requests before getting a list of items or example. Is there a more opaque way of doing this such that the client wouldn't need to do anything? I'm thinking something along the lines of CloudFront redirecting to the backup JSON file on the s3 bucket when it gets a 500 from the origin?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can handle this with AWS Route53 and healthchecks.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html

You will need to transfer your domain to AWS DNS Service.

Comment: thank you for your response. This looks good. Is there a solution that doesn't involve using Route53?